# Custom property for Zend DB Row

Tags: php, database, zend-framework

Consider code below:

```
$select = $table->select()->setIntegrityCheck(false);
$row = $table->fetchRow($select);

// this throws Specified column "custom_data" is not in the row
$row->custom_data = 123;

echo $row->custom_data;
```

How can I add some custom data to zend db row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add temporary data to the row object such that it doesn't actually get saved with the row, don't use attributes, use a setter method in your row class:

```
protected $customData = null;

public function getCustomData()
{
    return $this->customData;
}

public function setCustomData($data)
{
    $this->customData = $data;
    return $this;
}
```

Then just call that from your code:

```
$row->setCustomData($data);
```

Alternately, if you want to do this for many classes, you can override the __set() method of Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract such that instead of throwing an exception, it stores the value in a separate area:

```
protected $extraFields = [];

function __set($columnName, $value)
{
    $columnName = $this->_transformColumn($columnName);
    if (array_key_exists($columnName, $this->_data)) {
        $this->_data[$columnName] = $value;
        $this->_modifiedFields[$columnName] = true;
    } else {
        $this->extraFields[$columnName] = $value;
    }
}

public function __get($columnName)
{
    $columnName = $this->_transformColumn($columnName);
    if (array_key_exists($columnName, $this->_data)) {
        return $this->_data[$columnName];
    } else {
        return $this->extraFields[$columnName];
    }
}
```